# Python: Difference between i+=1 at the beginning and at the end of loop

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am learning the basics at the moment

I am now at a point where a question came up and I can't really find a answer to this.

**What is the difference between:**

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    if (i % 2) != 0: continue
    print(i)
print("End of loop")
```

**And
(line 3 moved to the end of the loop)**

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if (i % 2) != 0: continue
    print(i)
    i += 1
print("End of loop")
```

I can't really understand the problem because in PHP and JS, I always increased my number at the end of the loop because its better to read for me.

Perhaps a logic thing I need to remember in Python?

Comment: In the first case you increment `i` _before_ checking its parity, and in the second case you do it _after_.

Comment: Doing it at the start of the loop would mean your counter starts at 1; doing it at the end would first perform any operations with ```i = 0```, then only increment it to 1 (and so forth). When iterating through lists, doing it at the start of the loop would cause you to ignore the very first element within a loop (because list indices start at 0). Sometimes you want this, often you don't - if you do want it that way, it is probably better to increment at the end of the loop but start with ```i = 1``` (a more advanced way is to use a for loop with ```enumerate``` with a start value).

Comment: Also, I'd rather do `for i in range(10)` and avoid updating `i` by hand.

Comment: Thanks @ChaddRobertson my question is now clearer and I will try some things to understand the problem. The loop was just to try the continue function :)

Answer (score 0):

Helllo,

**First of all, it all depends on when you need to increment.**

In your case, the first code starts with incrementing, i.e. the condition starts at 1.

in second case, it will never increment, because you will check all the time condition, which always will return 0

Comment: So continue will always jump at the beginnig of the loop and ignores the rest of the code which is behind it?

Comment: yes, exactly, after continue, loop going Next